# (De)Serializing type with interface-based polymorphic properties into/from JSON

Tags: c#, json, polymorphism, system.text.json

First of all, I apologize for the length of below code; it's about as minimal as I could get it.

I'm trying to (de)serialize a dozen or so messages that are defined in a 3rd party library; I cannot modify these classes and interfaces in any way. The messages are all interface based; they share no baseclass unfortunately, just the `IMessage<T>` interface. Below are the messages; I've left out irrelevant properties like `Header` on an `IMessage<T>` etc. I've provided two of each message 'types', a `Foo` and a `Bar`, for demonstration purposes.

```cs
// Below types are defined by a 3rd party and cannot be modified
public interface IMessage<out T> where T : IMessageContent
{
    IMessageBody<T> Body { get; }
}

public interface IMessageBody<out T> where T : IMessageContent
{
    T Content { get; }
}

public interface IMessageContent {
    string MessageId { get; set; }
}

public class FooMessage : IMessage<Foo>
{
    public IMessageBody<Foo> Body { get; set; }
}

public class BarMessage : IMessage<Bar>
{
    public IMessageBody<Bar> Body { get; set; }
}

public class FooBody : IMessageBody<Foo>
{
    public Foo Content { get; set; }
}

public class BarBody : IMessageBody<Bar>
{
    public Bar Content { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IMessageContent
{
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string FooValue { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IMessageContent
{
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string BarValue { get; set; }
}
```

Since I cannot modify the above types, I cannot use `[JsonDerivedType]` attributes and such. I'm hoping [Configuring polymorphism with the contract model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0#configure-polymorphism-with-the-contract-model) will be the solution - but it may not be. I prefer to use `System.Text.Json` - though if absolutely necessary I will consider `NewtonSoft.Json`.

So here's what I'm trying to do:

```cs
var message1 = new FooMessage { Body = new FooBody { Content = new Foo { MessageId = "abc", FooValue = "foo" } } };
//var message2 = new BarMessage { Body = new BarBody { Content = new Bar { MessageId = "xyz", BarValue = "bar" } } };

var opt = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new MyMessageTypeResolver()
};

// Serialize a message
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message1.Body.Content, opt);
Console.WriteLine(json);
// Deserialize message
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IMessageContent>(json, opt);
```

For this purpose I have implemented a `MyMessageTypeResolver` which is passed into the serializer's `Serialize(...)` and `Deserialize(...)` methods.

```cs
public class MyMessageTypeResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonTypeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);

        if (typeof(IMessageContent).IsAssignableFrom(jsonTypeInfo.Type))
        {
            jsonTypeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions
            {
                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$type",
                IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
                UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
                DerivedTypes =
                {
                    new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo)),
                    //new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)),
                }
            };
        }

        return jsonTypeInfo;
    }
}
```

The above code works; it can be seen in action [in this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yoTj29). As you can see, a [type discriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0#polymorphic-type-discriminators) `"$type": "Foo"` is correctly added to the JSON.

However, the problem begins when I uncomment the `new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)),` line; this results in the following exception:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Specified type 'Bar' is not a supported derived type for the polymorphic type 'Foo'. Derived types must be assignable to the base type, must not be generic and cannot be abstract classes or interfaces unless 'JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FallBackToNearestAncestor' is specified.**

I've tried a lot of variations, but I can't get this to properly (de)serialize for the life of me. Any help or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated. The goal is to be able to (de)serialize `message1` and `message2` in above given code. I'm not dead set on using the `JsonTypeInfoResolver` route; any other way (that's manageable for a dozen, maybe more in the future, message types) that achieves this goal is welcome.

Comment: Are you using only 3rd party classes, but the code to serialize and deserialize yours?  I don't see any problem then. There is a standard option.

Comment: @Serge The types I'm trying to (de)serialize are 3rd party types. The (de)serialization code is mine. What do you mean: there is a standard option? I have [demonstrated](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yoTj29) the problem; I don't understand "I don't see any problem then"? It *literally* throws an exception as soon as I uncomment line 46 or try to deserialize `message2` from line 11 and 23 - 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (typeof(IMessageContent).IsAssignableFrom(jsonTypeInfo.Type))
{
    // Intermediate code snipped
    DerivedTypes = 
    {
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo)),
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)),
    }
```

You check to see whether `jsonTypeInfo.Type` is assignable to `IMessageContent`, and then add derived types `Foo` and `Bar`.  But **`IMessageContent` has many derived types, including `Foo` itself**.  Then when your code is invoked, it is actually attempting to assign the derived type `Bar` to `Foo`, which fails, because `Bar` is not a derived type of `Foo`.

To fix this, you should check that each incoming derived type is actually assignable to `JsonTypeInfoInfo.Type` before adding it.  Here is a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) that does that:

```
public class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> AddDerivedTypes(Type baseType, IEnumerable<Type> derivedTypes) => typeInfo => 
    {
        if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
            return;
        if (baseType.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type))
        {
            var applicableDerivedTypes = derivedTypes
                // Check to make sure the current derived type is actually assignable to typeInfo.Type (which might also be a derived type of baseType)
                .Where(t => typeInfo.Type.IsAssignableFrom(t));
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var type in applicableDerivedTypes)
            {
                if (first)
                    // TODO: decide what to do if typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions is not null (because e.g. it was initialized via attributes).
                    typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new JsonPolymorphismOptions
                    {
                        TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "$type",
                        IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = true,
                        UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization,
                    };
                first = false;
                typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions!.DerivedTypes.Add(new JsonDerivedType(type, type.Name));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

You would then use the modifier as follows:

```
var opt = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.AddDerivedTypes(typeof(IMessageContent), new [] { typeof(Foo), typeof(Bar) }) },
    }
};
```

Notes:

- I recommend customizing System.Text.Json contracts via [modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) rather than by inheriting from `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` because modifiers can more easily be combined and reused.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mn0vEU).

Answer (score -1):

You can not create a generic custom serializer, not even a generic method because all your generic interfaces have only {get;} (read only). Only concrete clases have setters. So the easiest way is to use the code like this for each of your third party classes

```
FooMessage fooMessage = new FooMessage { 
                 Body = JsonObject.Parse(json)["Body"].Deserialize<FooBody>()};
```